# Solving $a_1x_1 + \cdots +a_nx_n = b$

Tags: numerical-linear-algebra, finance

I'm glad to ask my first question on the maths site! So here we go. I'm trying to set up  prices right now and here is my problem :

I know that my customer has a certain amount of money available. This amount is known and fixed. So I would like to sell him my products to a certain price depending on their popularity. I have found that a good idea would be to use this popularity as a coefficient. (The popularity is also fixed and known, it is a percentage).

My goal is that the total price of all the products I'm selling doesn't exceed the amount of money my customer has. Therefore I ended up with this easy to find equation but I don't see how to solve it. $$a_1x_1 + \cdots +a_nx_n = b$$

For example, if my customer has $10$ dollars and if I have $20$ products to sell him, I would have this equation : $$a_1x_1 + \cdots + a_{20}x_{20} = 10$$

Where the $a_i$ are the popularity of each product. My goal is to find a repartition of the $x_i$ which is correlated with the $a_i$.

Thanks a lot

PS : I don't have a Phd so please... But I do have a MSc in Engineering. What I want to say is that I can understand advanced mathematics but start from the beginning of the story please ; )

**Edit**

My only criteria is that the repartition of the xi should reflect the repartition of the ai. For example if $a_2$ is the highest popularity, $x_2$ should be the highest price.

Comment: Should that last equation be `a1x1 + ... + a20x20 = 10` since there are $20$ products?

Comment: Oh yes, thank you sorry about that

Comment: Also, is this a correct interpretation? $x_i$ is the price of the $i$th item (which you are solving for), and $a_i$ is the "popularity" of the $i$th item (which is given), where the $a_i$ are normalized so that $\sum_{i=1}^n a_i = 1$?

Comment: Can we just set $x_1 = b/a_1$ and all other $x_i = 0$?  Is there some other criteria you would like you solution to fullfil?

Comment: (Sorry, I'll try to learn the formatting code of this site shortly) Yes xi is the price of the ith item, and ai its popularity. However the ai are not normalized. For example all products can have 100% popularity. I defined populaty as the number of people who enjoy the product divided by the total number of people who used it.

Comment: If you're looking to learn the formatting, [here's a helpful tutorial](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).  Everything you've posted has been readable, so don't stress it too much.

Comment: Thank you for the link! My only criteria is that the repartition of the xi should reflect the repartition of the ai. For example if a2 is the highest popularity, x2 should be the highest price

Comment: All right, I have an idea.  Before I put it down, I want to ask: are you sure about
$$
a_1x_1 + \cdots +a_nx_n = b?
$$
Let's do a quick sanity check: say there are two items.  One has popularity $1$, the other popularity $0.1$, and the customer has $\$10$.  Now we have
$$
x_1 + 0.1 x_2 = 10
$$
which would mean $x_1 = 9,x_2 = 10$ would be a valid solution.  Is this what you want?  Or, I guess we could do $x_1 = 9.9, x_2 = 1$

Comment: Yes exactly !!!

Comment: Euh sorry, no sorry I mistaken! The difference between 9 and 10 doesn't reflect enough the difference between 1 and 0.1.

Comment: Yes 9.9 and 0.1 is what I'm after, or 9 and 1.

Comment: Well wait a second: do you want $9.9$ and $0.1$ or $9.9$ and $1$?  Should we just have $x_1 + x_2 + \cdots + x_n = b$ instead?

Comment: Hum... actually I think that I don't understand your idea with 9.9 and 1, because the sum would be 10.9 which is superior to 10. Is there something I'm missing ? 
I'm don't think that we should remove the ais from the equation because then we don't have any way to "weight" the xis

Comment: Yes it seems that's what he's looking for since he wrote _"the total price of all the products I'm selling doesn't exceed the amount of money my customer has"_ and there is nothing in this sentence that suggests a weighted sum. That's what I went with in the answer I posted and didn't realise that the equation in the question was wrong until I saw your comment.

Comment: We "weight" the $x_i$ with another set of equations.  See my answer.

Comment: @red2nb No if you leave the $a_i$ in the equation, the sum of $x_i$ will not be equal to $b$ anymore (unless all $a_i$ are equal to $1$). Instead add other equations to account for the constraints between $a_i$ and $x_i$.

Comment: Thank you, I didn't realize this error. I have to re-read the whole thing and your explanations to fully understand it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think we can represent the desired criteria with the following system of equations
$$
x_1 + x_2 + \cdots + x_n = b
$$
and to enforce "reflection of the $a_i$" (assuming all $a_i$ are non-zero), we have
$$
x_1/a_1 = x_2/a_2 = \cdots = x_n/a_n
$$
Which gives us a system of $n$ equations on $n$ variables, which will have a unique solution.

We can find the solution as follows: define $t$ to be the common ratio $x_i/a_i$.  We have $x_i = a_i t$, so that
$$
a_1 t + a_2 t + \cdots + a_n t = b
$$
Which is to say
$$
(a_1 + \cdots + a_n)t = b \implies t = b/(a_1 + \cdots + a_n)
$$
Once we have $t$, substitute back to find $x_1 = a_1 t$, $x_2 = a_2 t$, and so on.

All together, we have
$$
x_i = \frac{a_i}{a_1 + a_2 + \cdots + a_n} \cdot b
$$

Comment: Thank you very much for your help and your patience. I don't have enough reputation to upvote, so I'm puzzled because both answers were really helpful. However I'm going to accept this answer since I'll begin with this approach and you were the first person to investigate it with me.

Comment: Just a question, what about if all $a_i$ are zero ? I've just realized that this situation will actually happen, and quite often. Can you suggest me an idea of how to deal with it ?

Comment: Oh I've just seen it ! Then I can just say that all $x_i=b/n$

Answer (score 1):

There will surely be more than one solution, since it is highly unlikely that you have as many products as you have equations (i.e. 1 product).

Therefore it is not a problem of solving this equation rather than finding an optimal set of prices $\left(x_1,\cdots,x_n\right)$.

- **Solution 1**

The "optimality" of this set will be defined by what is called an objective function (or cost function) that you will have to determine.

This cost function can, for instance, be the sum of all prices, or the average price, or even the standard variation of your price distribution. Anything you can think of and that would make the solution better suit your needs. You can also have multiple cost functions.

Then the goal would be minimising or maximising this/these cost function(s).

This is called an optimisation problem and there are several algorithms that work quite well on these.

- **Solution 2**

Just set the coefficient as the total price times the popularity weighted over the total popularity. I.e:

$$\forall i\in[1,n],  x_i = b\times\frac{a_i}{\sum_{k=1}^n a_k}$$

And you can check that if you sum all prices you get $b$:

$$\sum_{i=1}^n x_i = \sum_{i=1}^n b\times\frac{a_i}{\sum_{k=1}^n a_i} = b \times \sum_{i=1}^n \frac{a_i}{\sum_{k=1}^n a_k} = \frac{b}{\sum_{k=1}^n a_k} \times \sum_{i=1}^n a_i = b \times \frac{\sum_{i=1}^n a_i}{\sum_{k=1}^n a_k} = b$$

For example:

Say $b=10$ and you have 2 products with popularities $a_1=0.6$ and $a_2=0.2$. Then your prices would be:

$$x_1 = 10 \times \frac{0.6}{0.8} = 7.5$$

and

$$x_2 = 10 \times \frac{0.2}{0.8} = 2.5$$

Comment: The beauty of mathematics. I will go with solution 2 for now since it is the simplest but I am very interested in solution 1 and I'll learn optimization to move on it as soon as I can. Thank you for the clear explanations

Comment: @red2nb: see Omnomnomnom's answer to understand how I derived the $x_i$ in solution 2 ;)

Comment: (I'll upvote as soon as I have enough reputation. Please see my comment on Omnomnommom's answer). Thanks a lot for you help

Comment: @red2nb: That's only fair, Omnomnomnom's answer was indeed more detailed as for the derivation of the solutions :) Glad to be of help anyway !